# Mapping fields in SOLR for faceting

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, apache-tika, solr-cell

I'm indexing rich text documents into SOLR 3.4 using `ExtractingRequestHandler` and I'm having trouble getting it to behave like I want it to.

I would like to store creation date as a field to use for faceted search later and have defined the following in `schema.xml`:

```
<field name="creation_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I index like this:

```
curl -s "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=myid&resource.name=myfile.xls&commit=true" -F myfile=@/path/to/myfile.xls
```

I get the dynamic field `attr_creation_date` (that other rules make sure), but I don't get it as `creation_date`. I have also unsuccessfully tried to use `copyField` like so:

```
<copyField source="attr_creation_date" dest="creation_date"/>
```

Yet another try was putting this in `solrconfig.xml`, but no luck:

```
<str name="fmap.Creation-Date">creation_date</str>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic here. Any help is most appreciated!

Settings for `ExtractingRequestHandler` in `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" startup="lazy" 
    class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">

        <str name="fmap.content">text</str>
        <str name="fmap.Last-Save-Date">last_save_date</str>
        <str name="fmap.Creation-Date">creation_date</str>
        <str name="fmap.Content-Type">content_type</str>
        <str name="lowernames">true</str>
        <str name="uprefix">attr_</str>

        <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
        <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

My `schema.xml` file (lots of default stuff): https://gist.github.com/1358002

Comment: Should work if the file has the creation date. Can you post your ExtractingRequestHandler settings and schema.xml ?

Comment: worked fine with Solr 3.3 <date name="creation_date">2007-09-15T09:02:31Z</date>, if all fields are returned (fl=*). Does the document have date ?

Comment: Yes, the date is contained as `attr_creation_date`, but not as plainly `creation_date` as I wish.